# Test if single linked list is circular by traversing it only once

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, circular-list

I am a fresher and I was asked this question in a recent interview I gave.

The question was --- **By traversing each element of linked list just once find if the single linked list is circular at any point.**

To this I answered that we will store reference of each node while traversing the list in another linked list and for every node in the list being tested we will find if the reference exists in the list I am storing the references.

The interviewer said that he needs a more optimized way to solve this problem.

Can anyone please tell me what would be a more optimized method to solve this problem.

PS: By circular at any point I mean this. http://s22.postimg.org/g0iwevfnl/2013_06_30_15_56_34_362.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by `at any point`?

Comment: Means it need not be completely circular unlike a circular linked list which is completely circular.

Comment: So something like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/6n-graf.svg/333px-6n-graf.svg.png?

Comment: No. This is a graph. Linked lists are linear. They can point to only one node. Wait lemme draw a picture and upload it...

Comment: By circular at any point I mean this----http://s22.postimg.org/g0iwevfnl/2013_06_30_15_56_34_362.jpg

Comment: Oh i see, then my solution wont work. I don't see any other way other than storing every address to an array and check it for every visited node.

Comment: Did you ask any questions to clarify? Is Floyd's algorithm ruled out? Can you modify the list?

Comment: No I cant modify the list. We can only traverse it. Tortoise n Hare is straight away ruled out because of list being traversed twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interviewer is looking to see if you know a trick that is known officially as [`Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare), or `Tortoise and hare` unofficially.

The idea is to advance two pointers in a loop, one moving twice per iteration, and the other only once. If the fast-moving pointer catches up to the slow-moving one from behind, the list has a cycle.

This algorithm detects a cycle in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` storage. The "slow" pointer goes through the list no more than once, so it is fair to say that the algorithm finds an answer in a single traversal.

In my opinion this algorithm makes a poor interview question, because it is somewhat hard to come up with it on the spot, unless you know it ahead of time. At the same time, this is not a an algorithm that is used so widely that everyone must know it, making me wonder why anyone would ask about it in an interview.

Comment: "By traversing each element of linked list just once"

Comment: But sir it uses two pointers. The problem clearly mentioned traversing each element just once.

Comment: @user1589754 Are you positive that the interviewer asked for traversing each element just once? Could he say "by traversing the list just once"?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am nearly positive that the interviewer asked for a single traversal of the list, not for a single traversal of each element. Since the slow pointer goes through the list no more than once, I think it's fair to say that Floyd's cycle detection algorithm finds a loop in a single traversal.

Comment: hmmm... True.. This can be the answer to the problem. Thanks a lot sir. I am meeting them again tomorrow for the next round. They had told me to find a better way till then. As there seem to be no other possible way. I'll tell this method only. Hope they agree.:) :)

Comment: @user1589754 I don't think this answer fulfills requirement of single traversal, as the fast pointer traverses the list more than once.

Comment: @Tomas Although the fast pointer may very well visit the same element more than once, it would stop as soon as the cycle is found, which happens in a single path of a slow pointer, or `O(λ + μ)` (see the article linked in the answer).

Comment: But the algorithm as a *whole* should be single pass, so you cannot exclude the fast pointer from that. You cannot just say "but the slow pointer is single pass". This way I can construct whatever algorithm I want (quadratic, traversing `n` times, ... whatever) and then just add a slow pointer and say "yeah it is single pass". This algorithm is *not* single pass.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that the interviewer goal was to see if you know the **Floyd's cycle-finding** algorithm. The goal of such a question would be to see if you understand data-structures concepts such as lists, binary trees and hashes.

The main problem with your answer is that the algorithm you gave have a complexity of O(n^2), i.e. O(n) for traversing the original list * O(n) for checking if each node exists in the second list, in each iteration.

When the interviewer asked you to optimize your answer, you could have suggested replacing the second linked list with another data-structure that provide faster lookup than O(n). For instance a binary tree has an O(logn) lookup complexity and a hash has an O(1) lookup complexity (not always but this is a common assumption), which is significantly faster than using a second linked list that have a lookup complexity of O(n).

So an O(n) solution would be to replace your second linked list with a hash (i.e. HashMap, HashSet, etc).

Of course the **Floyd's cycle-finding** algorithm is a more elegant solution to this problem because it has a better memory complexity (i.e. no need to store the visited nodes in memory).

Comment: i agree with your answer - knowing floyd's method is a special trick and in the event if you dont know that trick how you approach the problem is main challenge

Answer (score 1):

A bit more efficient approach would be to have a single iterator & check for the the presence of a node pointing to null...  This approach should be twice more efficent than the above approach.

Comment: What if there is a loop in the list? Wouldn't it be an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
tempNode = list;

while((tempNode->next != list) && (tempNode->next != NULL))
     tempNode = tempNode->next;

if(tempNode->next == list)
   //list is circular
if(tempNode->next == NULL)
  //list is not circular

Above two conditions can be addressed in while loop also
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.